# Android programming how to use if and else statements to check if application exists

Tags: android

Dear overflow members i have just got help on launching a class from a differnt app using intents and i would now like to know if i would use "If" and "Else" to check if the package exists and if its does continue launching it but if it doesnt show a toast notifying the user that is doesnt exist and the way i am trying to launch intent is on button click.Thanks for help

Here is the block of code i want to add if and else to.

```
Button button91 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dlc);
        button91.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent("com.dlc.MainActivity.class"); startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: If i have done somthing wrong while posting my Question please just let me know so i can fix it.

Comment: Do you want to check that in the current package of your app or package of all other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if/else will not work as `startActivity()` throws exception if it fails, so you need to use `try/catch`:

```
Intent i=new Intent("com.dlc.MainActivity.class"); 

try {
  startActivity(i);
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    // start activiy failed - show toast etc...
}
```

And you should use `PackageManager`'s `getPackageInfo()` to find out if certain package exists.

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: No WebNet doesnt provide the exact answer to my question but it does lead me in the right direction so thanks.  pragnani could you help me

Comment: so how would i put try/catch into use in my situation

Comment: catching ActivityNotFoundException is better

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to play around with this and get this to work in your application. This is my example as I had to use this in my app due to Google not making their recent calendar app available to earlier versions. It checks whether the user has the app and if not, launches the Google Play Store on the app description page so that they can download it to use the functionality in the app. Hope this helps!

```
boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot("com.google.android.calendar");  
    if(installed)
    {               
        Intent launchCalendar = new Intent();
        String deviceVersion = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
        String[] versions = deviceVersion.split("\\.");
        ComponentName googleCalendar = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

        if (Integer.valueOf(versions[0]) > 2) {
            if (Integer.valueOf(versions[1]) > 2) {
                //Froyo or greater (mind you I just tested this on CM7 and the less than froyo one worked so it depends on the phone...)
                googleCalendar = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");               
            }

        } else {
            //less than Froyo
            googleCalendar = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");
        }

        launchCalendar.setComponent(googleCalendar);
        startActivity(launchCalendar);

    } else {
            Intent googleCalendarInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.calendar"));
            startActivity(googleCalendarInstall);
        Toast.makeText(DatesActivity.this, "Please install the Google Calendar app in order to use the calendar functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finish();
}

private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
           pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
           app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
           app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```